# Does a unitary transformation change the symmetry of a system?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, symmetry, unitarity

Assuming that I got a system with hamiltonian given by$$H=\sigma_x+\sigma_y$$where $\sigma_{x,y,z}$  denotes the Pauli operator. It's not hard to see that this hamiltonian has chiral symmetry respect to $\sigma_z$,i.e.,$$\sigma_zH\sigma^{\dagger}_z=-H$$Now I want to make a time-dependent transformation $U$ to the state of system,i.e., $$\left|\Psi \right>=U\left|\psi \right>=e^{-i\sigma_0t}\left|\psi \right>$$where $\sigma_0$ denotes the $2\times 2$ identity operator. Under this transformation, hamiltonian H must be tranformed into $\widetilde{H}$,$$\widetilde{H}=UHU^{\dagger}+i\frac{\partial U}{\partial t}U^{\dagger}$$ in order to satisfy with the Schrodinger equation$$i\frac{\partial \left|\Psi \right>}{\partial t}=\widetilde{H}\left|\Psi \right>$$ It's easy to obtain $\widetilde{H}$ with form given by$$\widetilde{H}=\sigma_0+\sigma_x+\sigma_y$$and as you can see, the chiral symmetry was broken because$$\sigma_z\widetilde{H}\sigma^{\dagger}_z\ne-\widetilde{H}$$due to the factor $\sigma_0=i\frac{\partial U}{\partial t}U^{\dagger}$. What's wrong with my calculation or my understanding?

Comment: Your calculation and conclusion are sound, cf. [interaction picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interaction_picture).  Normally, a symmetry is a unitary transformation of the hamiltonian which leaves it invariant, the same action it  has on the identity. Your "symmetry" is a parity-like reflection and lacks this property.

Comment: @CosmasZachos. Okay, I understand what you meaned. You said that the so-called "chiral" symmetry is not a conventional symmetry because when we talk about a symmetry of system like $A$ we always have $\left[H,A \right]=0$ instead of $\left\{H,A \right\}=0$ or anyting else. What really makes me confused about is whether this kind of time-dependent unitary transformations would change the physical properties due to the term $i\frac{\partial U}{\partial t}U^{\dagger}$.

Comment: It does what you found.